# Limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\int\limits_0^\pi\cos\left(x\sin\theta \right)d\theta=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

Consider the function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=\int_0^\pi\cos\left(x\sin\theta  \right)d\theta.$$
I showed that this function satisfies the following differential equation:
$$xf''(x)+f'(x)+xf(x)=0$$
this implies that
$$f''(x)+\frac{f'(x)}{x} +f(x)=0$$
since $f'$ is bounded then $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f''(x)+f(x)=0$$
how to continue to prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.$$

I am also interested if there's another method to prove it without the differential equation.

Comment: Would you allow to do a sub in the integral? That is, subbing away the sine, integrate wrt theta and then consider the limit?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9) helps?

Comment: @imranfat  yes how to do it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093915/show-the-limiting-forms-of-the-bessel-functions

Comment: the solution from the ode is: $f(x) = c_1 J(x)+c_2Y(x)$ and both of the Bessel functions go to zero as $x\to 0,$ so I guess that is a proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
f(x) = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x\sin\theta)\;d\theta
$$
change variables, $t = \sin\theta$
$$
f(x) = 2 \int_0^1\frac{\cos(xt)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\;dt
$$
But $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, so we may conclude from the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) that:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^1\frac{\cos(xt)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\;dt = 0 .
$$

Comment: i think when you split up the interval, $\sin(\theta+\frac \pi 2) = \cos(\theta)$

Comment: @dezdichado: $\sin(\pi-\theta) = \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: you are reducing the interval from $[0,\pi]$ to $[0,\pi/2]$ by that substitution?

Comment: I use that substitution to get $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cos(x\sin\theta)d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(x\sin\theta)d\theta$

Comment: i see it now, nice.

Comment: I first did my sutstituion $t=\sin\theta$ on $f(x) =  \int_0^{\pi} \cos(x\sin\theta)\;d\theta$ and Maple got the incorrect result $f(x) = \int_0^0\frac{cos(xt)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt$.  Why?  Because Maple incorrectly solved $t=\sin\theta$ as $\theta = \arcsin t$.